# Delete multiple text files in one folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from random import *
import os

def createFile(randomNumber):
    with open("FileName{}.txt".format(randomNumber), "w") as f:
        f.write("Hello mutha funsta")  

def deleteFile():
    directory = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(directory)
    fileList = [f for f in directory if f.endswith(".txt")]
    for f in fileList:
        os.remove(f)
print ("All gone!")  

fileName = input("What is the name of the file you want to create? ")
contents = input("What are the contents of the file? ")
start = input("Press enter to start the hax. Enter 1 to delete the products. ")
randomNumber = randint(0, 1)  

while True:
    if start == (""):
        for i in range(0):
            createFile(randomNumber)
            randomNumber = randint(0,9999)
        break
    elif start == ("1"):
        deleteFile()
        break
    else:
        print ("That input was not valid")
```

Above is code I've made to create as many text files as I specify (currently set to 0). I am currently adding a feature to remove all the text files created, as my folder now has over 200,000 text files. However, it doesn't work, it runs through without any errors but doesn't actually delete any of the files.

Comment: Please format your code in your question. The indentation is off

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is very wrong:

```
def deleteFile():
    directory = os.getcwd()
    os.chdir(directory)
    fileList = [f for f in directory if f.endswith(".txt")]
    for f in fileList:
        os.remove(f)
```

- you change the directory: not recommended unless you want to run a system call, mostly you change it to the current directory: it has no effect.
- your list comprehension doesn't scan the directory but a string => `f` is a character! Since it doesn't end with `.txt`, your listcomp is empty

To achieve what you want you may just use `glob` (no need to change the directory and pattern matching is handled automatically):

```
import glob,os
def deleteFile():
   for f in glob.glob("*.txt"):
      os.remove(f)
```

this method is portable (Windows, Linux) and does not issue system calls.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting all the files in the directory with name as `FileName{some_thing}.txt`, you may use `os.system()` as:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system("rm -rf /path/to/directory/FileName*.txt")
```

Comment: This only provides a pop-up window titles SyntaxError saying "(unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 9-10: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape."

Comment: There shouldn't be any errors if you've given the right path.

Comment: Well, it's is definitely the right path. But isn't working. The bracket after os.system is the highlighted problem, if that helps at all?

Comment: Ok, so my error was that i included 'C:', now it works, but doesn't delete the files?

Comment: this is really ugly. Python has standard ways of doing that. Like `glob.glob` for instance.